# Regular expression to extract a 10 digit mobile number from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to validate if my input argument is a 10 digit phone number, even if there is additional text in the input.

I have tried this:

```
numbemail("my numberis 0987654321") 
function numbemail(data){
var input =data;  
var numb = new RegExp(
   "\\+?\\(?\\d*\\)? ?\\(?\\d+\\)?\\d*([\\s\\-.]?\\d{2,})+", "g"
);
var numbresult = input.match(numb);
if(numbresult){
   var re=[]
   if(numbresult[0].length === 10){
      re.push(numbresult[0])
   } else if(numbresult[0].length < 10) {  
      re.push(numbresult[0]+" ==>(WrongNumber: you provided Number is less than 10 digits)</p>")
   } else if(numbresult[0].length > 10) { 
      re.push(numbresult[0]+" ==> (WrongNumber: you provided Number is more than 10 digits)</p>")
   }
   console.log(re)
   } 
}
```

When I tried this expecting 10 digits, but I got `numbresult[0].length= 11`

If I used a 10 digit string, then `numbresult[0].length= 10`

Expected Input:

> input = ("my mobile number is 9087654321")

Expected Output:

> "9087654321"

Comment: do you need to get 0 also, because the given question has 10 numbers  including 0

Comment: yes i need 0 also, not only 0 is input has 10 digit number means it has to trim,if input is ("my number 8 is 9087654321 ")expected output is 9087654321

Comment: okay got it, give some time will update it, any other cases do let me know

Comment: added answer with your use cases,  let me know if it worked for you

Comment: if input is ("90876543212345") i got 9087654321 this, but if a user entered 11 digit  his mobiles number by mistake, if its correct or not it will trim and fetch automaticaly right , so if input is more than 11 digit by beside we should report him

Comment: you can add the message at the else condiiton, check the answer, i think already in question you have that check

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
var regex = /[\+]?\d{10}/

let strings = ['my numberis 0987654321', 'my number 8 is 9087654321', 'my number 8 is 9087654321123', 'my number 8 is 9087654']


strings.forEach(str => {
 let output = str.match(regex)
 if(output){
   console.log('number is valid', output[0])
   return
 }
    console.log('number is not valid - kindly enter 10 digit mobile number', output)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your RegExp more simple. You write too complex code for simple task.

```
let input = "my numberis 0987654321";
// filter symbols which can separate phone number dights
input = input.split(" ").join("").split("-").join("");
let phoneNumber = input.match(/\d{10,}/)[0];
```

Comment: I think the asker is looking for one regex, rather than a combination with splits. Also seems like this is missing other phone number separators like parenthesis or periods.